# Sharepoint User Control can't search user by Japanese kanji name when type only 1 character

Tags: user-controls

I'm having a problem with search function of user control in Sharepoint.
User needs to **type** kanji name in this field to search for users.


If user inputs more than 2 Japanese characters, the search function will work well. However, if user only **types** 1 character (’大’, for example), this control doesn't return any result, but the expected result must be 17 users.

Any solution?


P/s Ignore the case of copy-paste, I care only about typing